# startup files inheritance in ipython

Tags: python, ipython

Suppose I have ipython profiles A and B. Both define their own configuration files (`A/ipython_config.py` and `B/ipython_config.py`) and startup files (`A/startup/startup.py` and `B/startup/startup.py`). Now I want B to inherit A stuff, so in `B/ipython_config.py` I include the following line:

```
load_subconfig('ipython_config.py', profile='A')
```

That's fine. But for the startup files part I couldn't find any useful hint. Do you know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There's no official support for running all the startup files from another profile, but you can make a startup script to find all the files in `profile_A/startup/` and execute them.